# not jquery click function

Tags: jquery, click

I want to set display: none; on an id, but only if you click the id itself and not the img in that id

```
    $(":not('#lightbox img'),#lightbox").click(function() {
        $("#lightbox").css( "display", "none" );
    });
```

can someone tell me how te get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `target` property of the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) object like

```
 $("#lightbox").click(function(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName != 'IMG'){
            $("#lightbox").css( "display", "none" );
        }
    });
```

**Update**

> only if you click the id itself

Then, check the `id` of the `target`

```
$("#lightbox").click(function(e) {
            if(e.target.id == 'lightbox'){
                $("#lightbox").css( "display", "none" );
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Do it just like you wrote but change the first line:

```
$('#lightbox').find("*").add("#lightbox").click(function (event) {
    $(this).is('img') ? event.stopPropagation() : $("#lightbox").css("display","none");});
```

Comment: I dont think this will work because doing `$("#lightbox").not('img')` will simply return an element with id `lightbox` that is not an `img`. This will not handle **children** of `lightbox` that arent images

Comment: fwiw, it still doesnt work http://jsfiddle.net/ammarcse/2nv7w8ys/1/ sorry I couldnt help more

Comment: ok, last try succeeded. thank you for the fiddle to practice with.